# exif.js only reads exif data from last photo with multiple select

Tags: javascript, jquery

Using exif.js v3.3.25
trying to get DateTimeOriginal from each photo before uploading
file.lastModified is not showing an accurate timestamp so exif data seemed like a better option.
The following code works with a single file select from a file input.
When selecting multiple files the DateTimeOriginal is only returned for the last file and all others are "undefined"

```
function fileSelected() {
var count = document.getElementById("fileData").files.length;
for (var index = 0; index < count; index ++) {
    var file = document.getElementById("fileData").files[index];
    EXIF.getData(file, function() {
        origtime = EXIF.getTag(file, "DateTimeOriginal");
        alert(origtime);
    }); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This has to do with the use of `var`.

Every time the loop runs, the `file` variable is overridden. Because the callback of `EXIF.getData` takes a bit of time to run, when it does, the value of `file` is the last file (because it was the last time the loop executed).

You'd think because they are inside a `{`, you'd get a new scope, but with `var` you don't (see [Hoisting](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Hoisting) for more details).

The simplest fix is just to replace `var` with either `const` or `let`. Now the blocks/scopes will work more intuitively and create a new variable every time.

```js
document.getElementById("fileData").onchange = function(e) {
  fileSelected();
};

function fileSelected() {
  const fd = document.getElementById("fileData");
  const count = document.getElementById("fileData").files.length;
  for (let index = 0; index < count; index++) {
    const file = document.getElementById("fileData").files[index];
    EXIF.getData(file, function() {
      out.innerHTML += `${file.name}: ${EXIF.getTag(file, "DateTimeOriginal")} ${EXIF.getTag(this, "DateTimeOriginal")}\n`;
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/exif-js"></script>

Select multiple images:
<input type="file" id="fileData" multiple>
<hr>
<pre id="out"></pre>
```

If you need to keep the `var` to support very old browsers, you could replace the usage of `file` with `this` inside `EXIF.getData`'s callback. Alternatively, you could use [IIFEs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to create new scopes.